# Symfony 3 orphanRemoval=true doesn't delete removed records from form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.1

I need t ocreate a bus adding form. Bus can have many amenities and that's why  I created OneToMany relationship between bus and bus amenities.

What I want to achieve is to let Doctrine to remove (or update) data from OneToMany table without looping or doing anything particular in controller. I read somewhere that you can use ***orphanRemoval=true*** annotation on Entity that will take care of that but for some reason it doesn't work...

I can update existing and add new amenities (new data) but I can't delete records that I previously removed from Edit form.

Can it be done using ***orphanRemoval=true*** or does someone know where is the problem with my code:

Here is the code:

Bus Entity (shorted version):

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BusVehiclesAmenities", mappedBy="bus", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $busVehiclesAmenities;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->busVehiclesAmenities = new ArrayCollection();
    }



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities busVehiclesAmenities
     * @return BusVehicles
     */
    public function addBusVehiclesAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities)
    {

       /* if ($this->busVehiclesAmenities->contains($busVehiclesAmenities)) {
            return;
        }*/
        $this->busVehiclesAmenities->add($busVehiclesAmenities);
        $busVehiclesAmenities->addBus($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities
     */
    public function removeBusVehiclesAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities)
    {
        $this->busVehiclesAmenities->removeElement($busVehiclesAmenities);
        $busVehiclesAmenities->addBus(null);


    }
    /**
     * Get busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getBusVehiclesAmenities()
    {
        return $this->busVehiclesAmenities;

    }
    /**
     * Set busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function setBusVehiclesAmenities($busVehiclesAmenities)
    {
        $this->busVehiclesAmenities = $busVehiclesAmenities;

    }
```

Amenities Entity:

```
private $bus;
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Amenities", inversedBy="amenities")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="amenities_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $amenities;

/**
 * @var float
 * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float", scale=2)
 */
protected $price;

public function __construct()
{
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


/**
 * Get busId
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getBus()
{
    return $this->bus;
}

/**
 * Add bus
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehicles
 *
 * @return BusVehiclesAmenities
 */
public function addBus(BusVehicles $bus)
{

    $this->bus = $bus;

    //$bus->setBusVehiclesAmenities($this);


    return $this;
}
```

Controller:

```
 public function editAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $busRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:BusVehicles');
        $bus = $busRepository->find($id);
        $editForm = $this->createForm(BusVehiclesType::class, $bus);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $entity = $editForm->getData();
            dump ($entity);
            $em->persist($entity); //this should take care of everything saving the manyToMany records

            $em->flush();

            // Adding flash message to our user

            $this->addFlash('success', 'New vehicle successfully added');


            //  return $this->redirectToRoute('bus_add');

        }
        return [
            'form' => $editForm->createView(),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're removing items from post? Because your code seems fine.

Comment: @DonCallisto . Yeah I am sure. When I debug form data) I get data that was edited and sent to form. I can show you debug output if you like to.

Comment: No, that's not necessary but sound like really strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem but looking at your code I notice that you're calling

```
$busVehiclesAmenities->addBus(null);
```

instead of

```
$busVehiclesAmenities->setBus(null);
```